# How to make a crystal report with my own sql statement

Tags: c#, sql

hi i would like to ask if how to make a crystal report in c# Which i can customized the elements of my report by using an sql statement, i have tried to make a report but it shows all data in my choosen table on my database, i would like to be specific date, or even specific year[image: Here's the example of my generated crystal report, thanks for the help]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an domain object (POCO) that maps to your database query
2. Write the C# to extract the query into a collection of your domain object.  There should be no shortage of articles on how to accomplish this, in the event you have no idea what I'm talking about
3. On your Crystal report's data source, bind it to your object collection

If any of this is unclear, let me know.